# Security of NameVirtualHost in regard to HTTP request forgery

Tags: apache-2.2, security, http, namevirtualhost

If I understand the concept of NameVirtualHost correctly it works by reading the Host variable of every HTTP request and matching it to a `ServerName` in any active VirtualHost directive with the matching interface and port. If it finds a matching `ServerName` the content of this VirtualHost is served to the client.

The Host variable can be easily forged by a client. So in the following configuration:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /super/secret/files
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/webserver
ServerName www.example.org
</VirtualHost>
```

a client could simply pass `localhost` as the value for Host and get access to the secret files. So you can't rely on the `ServerName` and have to use the `Order`,`Allow`,`Deny` (OAD) directives.

1. Are these assumptions correct?
2. If I protect a VirtualHost `example.org/phpmyadmin` with OAD the user still gets the `403 Forbidden` error. How would I configure apache to not even serve this VirtualHost on non localhost connections? A separate `<NameVirtualHost localhost:80>` maybe?

Answer (score 3):

The `Host:` header is only checked against `VirtualHost`s which are listening on the interface/IP address the request came in on. The wildcard means that the virtual host can be used for requests from any interface.

If you don't want people to access the `localhost` virtual host, then specify its IP addresses explicitly, rather than allowing it to be served from all interfaces:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 [::1]:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ....
```

P.S. You *do* need to specify the IPv6 address for localhost, as it *is* in use on any modern system, and is preferred over IPv4 by default.

Comment: An answer to 1. would make your answer complete. I still don't know how much apache relies on the `Host:` header.

Comment: Yes, that is how name-based virtual hosting works.